# Trying to initialize a data-member in the constructor, but it fails. Why?

Tags: c++, struct, instance-variables

Member variables of a struct pointer are returning the wrong number.

Here's the struct declaration:

```
struct Obj {
    int val;
    Obj(int val) { val = val; }
};
```

Here's where it gets funky:

```
Obj* cool = new Obj(4);
cout << cool->val; // outputs a number that's not 4
cout << (cool->val == 4); // prints 0... interesting
```

Comment: `this->val = val`. You should probably compile with warning turned on, they'd point that out in a heartbeat.

Comment: Really, `cool` should just be `Obj cool(4);`. You don't see people going around doing `std::string *s = new std::string("abc");` every time they need an object (at least I hope not).

Comment: And `cool->val == 4` is an equality check therefore a `bool`, which is 0 if false, 1 if true. As you have seen in your previous statement, `cool->val` is not 4, therefore it prints 0 for false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why am I getting these weird numbers?

You never initialize `Obj::val`, so the value is just what happens to be at that memory location at the point of constructing an instance of `Obj`.

---

#### REASON: The names are playing *"hide & seek"*

```
struct Obj {
    int val;         // (A)
    Obj(int val) {   // (C)
      val = val;     // (B)
    }
};
```

Inside the constructor of `Obj` the parameter named `val` is hiding the *data-member* named `val`; you are, in other words, assigning the value of the argument named `val`, to the argument named `val`.

The Standard says that a variable declared in a more narrow scope than a previous declaration will effectively hide the old on.

This means that since the argument `val` at (*B*) is in a more narrow scope than (*A*), at the point of (*C*) the compiler thinks you are referring to the argument.

---

#### Proposed Solutions

You have a few alternatives to fixing this issue

```
this->val = val;              // (A)
Obj::val  = val;              // equivalent
```

```
Obj (int val) : val (val) { } // (B)
```

```
Obj (int foo) { val = foo; }  // (C)
```

- *A*), use `this->val` to explicitly state that you'd like to assign the value to the data-member of *Obj*
- *B*), use the *mem-initializer* where `Obj::val` won't be hidden by the argument name
- *C*), change the name of your argument

---

#### The *mem-initializer* looks spooky, why is it included?

Out of the *Proposed Solutions*, the solution marked (*B*) is the preferred one.

It is called using the *mem-initializer*, and will initialize the member *val* with the value of the argument *val* directly upon calling the constructor; instead of it first having to be default initialized, and later assigned a value.

It's recommended to also not have arguments with the same name as member-variables, since it can be error prone if one forgets about *name-hiding*.

A common design is to prefix every *data-member* with `m_` to explicitly state that such is indeed a member of the instance, such as in the following snippet:

```
struct Obj {
    Obj(int val) : m_val (val) { }
    int m_val;
};
```

Comment: I disagree with your preference for solution (B).  The solution (C) has less ambiguities than (B).  I have never had any problems with (C) especially in code reviews.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews **rhetorical question**: how would you use option (C) if the data-member cannot, or preferably shouldn't, be default constructed?

Comment: My mistake.  I disagree with (B) because the argument name is the same as the data member name.  I suggest: `Obj (int val) : m_val(val) {}`.  IMO, this is more readable than keep the same name.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews certainly, but the options are written in a way to show the minimal change necessary, I will however update the post with a statement saying that one should prefer to also rename the data-member.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Obj(int val) { val = val; }
```

is just assigning the parameter to itself, and leaving the member variable containing garbage.  You need:

```
Obj(int val) : val(val) {}
```

or (if you really need to assign rather than initialise):

```
Obj(int val) { this->val = val; }
```

or:

```
Obj(int the_val) { val = the_val; }
```

You might want to consider using a naming convention for members:

```
int m_val;
Obj(int val) : m_val(val) {}
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the idiomatic way to *initialize* a data member in a constructor. I.e. you wouldn't expect any of the forms you show here in real code.